# InteruptedException

Tags: java, исключения

Здравствуйте долго искал в интернете но не нашел в каком случае бросает `InteruptedException` если не сложно объясните, что это такое в каком случае можно увидеть этот exception, checked или unchecked, и если не сложно покажите пример кода взывающий этот `Exception`?

Comment: все таки было бы неплохо показать нам ко, где возникает этот экспешен) Так то это прерывание, но чтобы сказать что-то конкретное...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может бросаться некоторыми методами в случае прерывания потока: например `sleep()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (true) {
                    sleep(20);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
    thread.interrupt();
    }
```

Создаём новый поток `thread`, в блоке try запускаем бесконечный цикл с методом, который усыпляет этот поток на 20 мс, когда из основного потока мы выставляем у `thread` флаг `interrupted` в `true` методом `interrupt()`, `sleep()` бросает `InterruptedException`, который мы ловим в блоке catch и выводим в консоль.
Можно использовать как способ остановки потока из другого потока.
Это так, чисто для примера.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Уважаемый Евгений пожалуйста можете объяснить эта строка ...................когда из основного потока мы выставляем у thread флаг interrupted в true методом interrupt()

Comment: когда мы запускаем метод main, он выполняется в основном потоке "main". Мы можем создать и запустить параллельный поток Thread, в котором будет происходить работа. Поток имеет флаг interrupted, значение которого мы можем получить методом isInterrupted(), возвращающим значение типа boolean. изначально он равен false. Вызывая метод interrupt() у потока мы переводим значение флага в true и методы которые могут кинуть InterruptedException бросают его, в данном случае метод sleep().

Comment: А вообще лучше погуглить многопоточность, чтобы не растекаться мыслью по древу.

Comment: Спасибо все было понятно очень благодарю вам спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

`InterruptedException` сигнализирует о том, что поток просит завершить его работу. Исключение относится к проверяемым и генерируется в том случае, когда метод проверяет был прерван текущий поток.В положительном случае генерируется `InterruptedException`. Он генерируется многими методами стандартной библиотеки.

JVM может сообщить о том, что поток прерывают двумя способами. Первый это бросить выше описанное исключение. Второе это использовать флажок потока `INTERRUPT`. Узнать это можно методом `interrupted()`.

Comment: Спасибо Огромное